# LinkControl - how to toggle opensInNewTab

Tags: block-editor

When I click the "open in new tab" toggle, nothing happens in the UI. The onChange is triggered. How do I set the toggle to true?

I am using the following:
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-editor/src/components/link-control#settings

Here is my current link control component

```
<LinkControl
            searchInputPlaceholder="Add Link"
            value={attributes.link}
            onChange={ ( value ) => {
                setAttributes({ link: value.url, opensInNewTab: value.opensInNewTab})
            }}
            settings={[
                {
                    id: 'opensInNewTab',
                    title: 'Opens in new tab',
                }
            ]}

            suggestionsQuery={ { type: "post", subtype: 'page' } }
        >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the documentation section directly above the one you linked, for `value`:

> A link `value` is composed of a union between the values of default
> link properties and any custom link `settings`.
>
> The resulting default properties of `value` include:
>
> - `url` (`string`): Link URL.
> - `title` (`string`, optional): Link title.
> - `opensInNewTab` (`boolean`, optional): Whether link should open in a new    browser tab. This value is only assigned when not providing a
>   custom `settings` prop.

So you'd need to include it in the value:

```
<LinkControl
    searchInputPlaceholder="Add Link"
    value={{
        url: attributes.link,
        opensInNewTab: attributes.opensInNewTab,
    }}
    onChange={(value) => {
        setAttributes({ link: value.url, opensInNewTab: value.opensInNewTab })
    }}
    settings={[
        {
            id: 'opensInNewTab',
            title: 'Opens in new tab',
        },
    ]}
    suggestionsQuery={{ type: "post", subtype: 'page' }}
/>
```